# How to test ActiveRecord callbacks with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, callback

How to test the following example?

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :discussion, touch: true
end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set a [message expectation](https://rspec.info/documentation/3.5/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/MessageExpectation.html):

```
it "should touch the discussion" do
  post = Factory.build(:post)
  post.discussion.should_receive(:touch)
  post.save!
end
```

This examples uses [factory_bot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot), but you could use fixtures or mocks as well.

Comment: It always amazes me how simple and elegant Ruby/Rails/Rspec is.

Comment: This really isn't a 'good' solution 1) it's slow because you are hitting the database and 2) you aren't testing that the touch got called as part of after_save callback, it could be hit by any one of the validations or callbacks that happen as part of saving an AR record.

Comment: @Intentss Agree. What's a better approach?

Comment: @Intentss makes a valid point. Using Shoulda callback matchers as suggested in the other answer is one approach. You might also consider omitting a test of the callback itself, and simply checking that the DB row was touched. Obviously this is slower, but it is easier to write and maintain the test, and you are testing behavior instead of implementation.

Answer (score 9):

### Firstly

If all you're trying to do is assert that the `touch: true` option is set on your association, then you can just do the following:

```
describe Post do
  it { should belong_to(:discussion).touch(true) }
end
```

### Secondly

For testing callbacks in general, read on.

All of the other answers here have two flaws:

1. They require a hit on the database, which can be slow.
2. They do not determine *which* callback is called during a `save!`

Instead, use the **[Shoulda Callback Matchers](https://github.com/beatrichartz/shoulda-callback-matchers)**, which doesn't require a database hit and you can specify which callback you're testing the existence of.

#### Installation

Install the [Shoulda Callback Matchers](https://github.com/beatrichartz/shoulda-callback-matchers) with Bundler:

```
group :test do
  gem "shoulda-callback-matchers", "~> 1.0"
end
```

#### Usage

```
it { should callback(:some_method).after(:save) }
```

*Thank you to [Beat](https://github.com/beatrichartz) for writing this great library.*

Answer (score 1):

You can mock the #touch call, or verify the effects of your callback on it.

```
it "should touch the discussion" do
  original_updated_at = @discussion.updated_at
  @post.save!
  @post.discussion.updated_at.should_not_be == original_updated_at
end
```